# Scala Spark - Convert a Dataframe into a nested Dataframe without case class?

Tags: scala

Data source is CSV file -> reading into DF -> making nested DF -> writing to Json

I want to take a flattened DF and convert the schema into a nested DF.

For EX:
DF1 schema: `|c0|c1|c2|c3|`

nested DF schema:

Header
|c0|c1|

Body |c3|c4|

Approach #1:
using StructType and StructFields, create a schema.
Use this schema to created nested DF.

Approach #2:
Is it possible to define schema while writing DF to Json?

Any suggestions on how to implement will be helpful.

Comment: Approach #1 is probably a better way of doing it, rather than hacking your way to break the row into a nested JSON.

Comment: How would I go on to implement approach #1.. is there any links I can refer to for nested StructType?

Comment: This should help you to get started. https://kb.databricks.com/scala/convert-flat-df-to-nested-json.html